# How do you make sure that the signed in user to Excel client is the same user (same email address) as the one that's signing in to your add-in?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am building an Excel Addin. I'll need to authenticate the user and publish the addin to AppSource. I have the following use case.

1. A user is signed in to Office 365 Excel client with his / her email address `email1@testuser.com`.
2. The same user will be asked to sign in to our Office add-in, using an email address. He / she will have to enter the email address separately, due to Dialog API / or alternative sign-in method requirements.

**Question 1:** How can we ensure that the user enters the same email address as they are signed in to the Office client? Or alternatively detect if they are using a separate address?

To give an example, they can sign-in with a completely different `email2@outlook.com` at the time of sign-in even though they are signed in to Excel with `email1@testuser.com`.

**Question 2:** Is it possible to get the email / user details at the time of installation of the add-in? If so, how?

Comment: Are you intending to sign the user in outside of the add-in scope (ex: through a web page?) You question is a bit confusing, it sounds like all you want to do is to sign in the user through the add-in, then you can use the graph API to get user details.

Comment: @Mavi Domates How does add-in know that user has typed the same `email_1` in `Dialog API pop up` which he used, to sign-in, in sheet?
`Dialog API pop up` will also authenticate a user sign in with `email_1` and use  `email_2` in `Dialog API pop up`.

Comment: Ah I think now I get it - you're talking about the signed in user to Excel. So the question is how do you make sure the signed in user to Excel client is the same user (same email address) as the one that's signing in to your add-in?

Comment: @Mavi Domates yes

Comment: Editing the question to better reflect what you're asking. Can you also elaborate on why you need this scenario?

Comment: As an example, do you absolutely need the user to sign-in?

Comment: @Mavi Domates I need to keep record of users who have installed my add-in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205661/discussion-between-mavi-domates-and-ozil).

Comment: @Mavi Domates anyupdate?